# Collect Parts of a String representing <img> Tags into a List in Java 8

Tags: java, string

There is a use case in which I have a long `String` which can contain many `<img>` tags.
I need to collect the entire image tag from start(`<img src="`) to close(`">`) in a List.

I wrote a regex(`"<img.*?\">"gm`) for seleting these but don't know how to collect them all in a List.

eg:

```java
final String regex = "<img.*?\\\">";
final String string = "Hello World <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/777\"> \nMy Name <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/ff2\"> Random Text\nHello\nHello Random <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/888\"> \nMy Name <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/2ff\">adaad\n";
final String replace = "";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

final String result = matcher.replaceAll(replace); // Here, how can I collect all the image tags in a list
```

Comment: You can make use of `#start`, `#end`, and `#group` under the `Matcher` class to pull this information out. It'd be a matter of iterating the groups in your match, and adding them to a list yourself. Note that if your regex was encompassing more than a single tag per group (e.g. `<img ...> ... </img>`, you'd run into the limitations of regex, and would likely need an html parser instead.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't try to reinvent html parsers. There's no need and you won't do it as well as those who write them for a living

Comment: https://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Java 8 - [`Pattern.splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence))

We can split the given string using so-called *Lookaheads* and *Lookbehinds* (*for more information, check the reference provided below*):

- `(?<=.)(?=<)` - matches a position between a character of any kind and an opening angle bracket `<` (*i.e. it captures an empty substring between any character and beginning of a tag*).
- `(?<=>)(?=.)` - matches a position between a closing angle bracket `>` and any kind of character.

```
public static final Pattern ANGLE_BRACKETS =
    Pattern.compile("(?<=.)(?=<)|(?<=>)(?=.)");
```

By using this Pattern, we generate a stream of substring stilted on an empty string on the border of opening and closing angle brackets. And then filter the strings that represent a valid image-tag.

```
final String string = "Hello World <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/777\"> \nMy Name <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/ff2\"> Random Text\nHello\nHello Random <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/888\"> \nMy Name <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/2ff\">adaad\n";

List<String> imageTags = ANGLE_BRACKETS.splitAsStream(string)
    .filter(str -> str.strip().matches("<img[^<]+>")) // verifying that a string is a valid image tag
    .toList();
        
imageTags.forEach(System.out::println);
```

- Information on [*Lookaheads and Lookbehinds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zq4)

## Java 9 - [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results())

In the regular expression, you need to care about the opening angle bracket `<` (not quotation mark) to ensure that a captured substring contains only one tag:

```
public static final Pattern IMG_TAG = Pattern.compile("img[^<]+>");
```

Using Java 9 method `Matcher.results()` we can create a stream of `MatchResult` objects, which contain information about captured sequences in the given string. And to obtain the matching substring, we can use `MatchResult.group()`.

```
final String string = "Hello World <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/777\"> \nMy Name <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/ff2\"> Random Text\nHello\nHello Random <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/888\"> \nMy Name <img src=\"https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/2ff\">adaad\n";
    
List<String> imageTags = IMG_TAG.matcher(string).results() // Stream<MatchResult>
    .map(MatchResult::group)                               // Stream<String>
    .toList();
        
imageTags.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/777">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/ff2">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/888">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/2ff">
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zpR)

Comment: Can you please provide the import statements as well?

Comment: @NitinKumar Sure, here's a link to [Online Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zpR) (*all required imports are specified at the top*).

Comment: @NitinKumar I've understood why you were asking for imports. `Matcher.results()` was added with Java 9 (if you're on Java 8, it wouldn't be available). I've provided an alternative Java 8 compliant solution based on `Pattern.splitAsStream()` (I'll explain how it works in a minute).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
     result.add(matcher.group());
}
```

and get rid of your `final String replace = "";`